# Webpack hot module replacement, how to configure watched directories

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

I'm on `webpack 5.x` and `webpack-dev-server 4.x` and use *hot module replacement*.
In certain cases, I want to watch an imported module from `node_modules` and use the hot module replacement on this as well.

I can't find how to configure the list of watched directories to add `node_modules/<my module>`

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled using Webpack [Cache](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/). You have to use the [`managedPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#cachemanagedpaths) feature of the Webpack Cache. By default, it is set to `['node_modules']`. It is now being migrated under [`snapshot` object](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#managedpaths). The directory/file paths that you provide to this options tells Webpack that it is managed by a package manager like npm or yarn. Thus it can be considered constant and doesn't change meaning it can be cached by Webpack.

The only catch is that documentation says that it only takes array of string values (directory paths) and it doesn't support **Regular Expressions** and it is a allow-list (whitelist) instead of reject-list. So, if you have 100s of node_modules, you would have to read them using glob and then provide those all as strings of array except for the one that you want Webpack to watch.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const allModules = fs.readdirSync('./node_modules');

const managedPaths = allModules.filter((moduleDir) => {

  const moduleName = path.basename(moduleDir);

  return moduleName !== 'module-to-watch';
});


module.exports = {
  // ...other options
  snapshot: {
    managedPaths
  }
};
```

#### Update

[Looking at the TypeScript declarations](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/types.d.ts#L10971) in the Webpack respository seem to suggest that it now accepts `RegExp` as value. However, it is not documented properly on Webpack.